# Triple Scalar Product $=0\implies $Spanning a Plane? (and Checking for Colinearity)

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have three vectors, $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$, and their scalar triple product equals zero, that is $\vec{a}\times \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c}=0$, then I understand that it means the vectors are coplanar, and so they can not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My first question is can I say they span a plane? My book really doesn't talk about it much.

My second question is there a way to check for two vectors being colinear in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question:** No.  They could span a line and still have a zero triple product.

**Second question:** Yes.  If two 3D vectors are co-linear their cross product will be zero.  Non-zero cross product means that they span a plane.

Comment: I know if two vectors' cross product is 0 it means the vectors are parallel, but that doesn't mean the same thing as colinear does it? I thought colinear meant that both vectors were on the same line.

Comment: Also how would you know if they spanned a plane or a line for the first question? Could I take the cross product of any of the vectors and see if equals 0? I assume if it was zero then it would be colinear?

Comment: If two vectors are colinear  then one of them is the scalar multiple of other, therefore their cross product will be zero (because the matrix will have two rows which are scalar multiple of each other). Now any two nonzero vectors which are not scalar multiple of each other spans a plane. Therefore is two vectors have nonzero cross product then they will span a plane. The normal to this plane will the the cross product.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan, Your first comment: co-linear means that they are on the same line.  Your second comment: Yes, if the cross product of any of the two vectors is non-zero, then they at least span a plane.  If their triple product is non-zero then they span $\mathbb R^3$.